ANDROID - ActivityResultLauncher intent extra return null on ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
I'm trying to add a captured image in the external private storage space of my app.
To do this, I have create a file object with getExternalFilesDir.
    public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", new Locale("fr_FR")).format(new Date());
        Random rdm = new Random();
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_" + rdm.nextInt(1000000000) + ".jpg";

        return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageFileName);
    }

After this, I'm getting the URI with FileProvider and the File object created. I send it to pictureAddResult with an intent putExtra. At this time my Uri appears correct.
intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

if(intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
   File photoFile;

   try {
      photoFile = ImageUtils.createImageFile(this.requireContext());
   } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }

   Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.requireContext(), "com.b2o.rfnd.fileprovider", photoFile);

   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
   pictureAddResult.launch(intent);
}

But here, when I trying to get my Uri with getParcelableExtra, it is null all the time.
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pictureAddResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Intent intent = result.getData();
                if (intent != null) {
                    // all the time null
                    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                    Log.i("imageuri", String.valueOf(imageUri));
                }
            }
        }
    );

I found a lot of informations when I tryed to found solution on internet but nothing about mine ...
In my manifest, I have add the provider
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.b2o.rfnd.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>


   // file path
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <external-files-path name="images" path="Pictures" />
   </paths>

and the queries
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

I think is come from my Provider but I have no idea of what is the problem.

That extra is never returned to you. At most, there would be an extra named data, but that would only be if you requested a thumbnail by not including EXTRA_OUTPUT in your outbound Intent.

@CommonsWare So how can I retrieve it in my result of pictureAddResult with the real size image ? Otherwise, there is an other solution of my problem ?

You already know where it is supposed to be. It should be in photoFile.

@CommonsWare If I understand correctly, i need to pass the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with my uri in the intent without use it. And I get the uri by making photoFile param of my class to get it globaly ?

I do not have enough of your code to tell you what specifically to do with photoFile. I can tell you that you are asking the user's camera app to store the photo in the location identified by photoFile in the code in your question.

Ok I will try somethink with it ! thank you :)
